# Automatic library generation for JSON

Tags: json, serialization, protocol-buffers, code-generation

Is there a tool like Google's Protobuf for JSON? I know you can convert from a Protobuf format to JSON but that requires a whole lot of extra serialization/deserialization, and I was wondering if there is some kind of tool that lets you specify the structure of a JSON message and then automatically generates libraries for use in a specified language (direct serialization/deserialization not just a wrapper around Protobuf's JSON formatter class)

I know nearly all languages provide their own in house way of handling JSON, and many higher level ones even allow you to avoid the boiler plate parsing code, but I was looking for a universal tool where you would only need to specify the format once, and then just get the generated libraries for use in multiple languages.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "extra serialization/deserialization" means. If you only use the protobuf-generated classes to convert to/from JSON, where's the extra serialization? Sure, there are still issues like code bloat (protobuf has a lot of features you won't use), and it might not be the best JSON parser possible, but maybe it isn't *that* bad.

Comment: As you said the extra serialization/deserialization occurs when you "convert to/from JSON"

Comment: Well, that's going to happen anyway, isn't it? Even if you're just parsing JSON into dicts of strings, that would count as a "deserialization step".

Answer (score 0):

The Protobuf equivalent would be [JSON-Schema](https://json-schema.org/), but still is language dependent on having a serializer or code generator available, just as Protobuf is.

If you're looking at making a REST-API, then OpenAPI Spec + swagger-codegen could be an option.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but isn't JSON-Schema just for describing the structure. There is no concept of "compiling" the JSON-Schema into libraries that provide serialization/deserialization api's from multiple languages like there is in Protobuf?

Comment: There are libraries that pass schema along with data, similar to Apache Avro for JSONSchema. But Object Mapping is just taking the schema into a language specific model... If you want an API, then use OpenAPI

Comment: Just want to update you that top contributors to Swagger Codegen has started a fork called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator), which seems to be more actively maintained.